# PHP display html fields based on php result

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a piece of PHP code that tells me if something happened or not. Based on the result I want to be able to display some HTML fields. I know I can achieve this in javascript/jQuery however I don't think breaking up the PHP code with javascript is a good idea for ease of reading.

What is the best way to achieve this?

EXAMPLE:

```
<?php

$result = 1;

if (result == 1) 
{
    display some html input fields where

} else 
    {
        hide some html input fields
    }

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _hide some html input fields_ Yuo may need to be more specific there.

Comment: You should conditionally display the data you want displayed, instead of hiding data that has already been displayed.  PHP isn't designed to work in the way you're describing, where HTML was added, and then modified by PHP.

Comment: *"What is the best way to achieve this?"* That could all depend on what `fields` you want to display and how many of them. You could simply place that `php` code in the location of where you want those fields to appear and `echo` them. as for hiding fields why not just avoid rendering them so you don't have anything to hide.

Comment: So if a link automatically generated link has expired (which I use in my code), I want to be able to remove two input boxes so the user can't enter anything. And instead of the input boxes I want to display some text.

Comment: If someone could provide me with an enample or point me in the right direction that would be great. Many thanks

Comment: @harry4912 - you haven't provided enough information to create an example.  You should provide relevant sample code demonstrating your current functionality and explaining in detail what you are doing / planning to do and why it isn't working / you think it will not work.

Comment: you will need to be able to check if the *"link"* has expired before the page renders since `php` runs server-side so where is this *"link"* and how/where are you checking if it has expired. Please give more relevant details as this could become a guessing game.

Comment: Have figured it out, was been stupid. Wanted something like this: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/scalar.php thanks for you help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [Alternative Syntax for Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

```
<?php
    // PHP code stuff only up top.
    $result = 1;
?>

<?php if ($result == 1) : ?>

    <p>Hello this is some text.</p>

<?php else : ?>

    <p>Here is some more stuff happening</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```